# Quarkus error: release version 17 not supported

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm new to learning quarkus and was trying to run a new project but here's an error for the same.
Using Openjdk11.0 on Windows 10

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< org.acme:backe >---------------------------
[INFO] Building backe 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                           
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile @ backe
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\btripathi\Project\backe\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-30T15:26:13+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.16.0.Final:dev (default-cli) on project backe: Fatal error compiling: error: **release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]**
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I checked with jdk versions and did try running but I don't think I understand the root cause of the issue.

Comment: What does your `pom.xml` look like?

Comment: <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>

Comment: <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>

Comment: I changed the maven compiler release to 11 and it worked ;---;

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: removed the image, thank you.

Comment: If you want to compile for Java 17, you need to use Java 17 (e.g. OpenJDK 17) and not Java 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem where I made changes to `pom.xml` file. change the maven compiler release to same as that of jdk version, it works for me.

```
<properties>
<compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
```